# Get replaced characters with javascript regex replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently replacing all non-letter characters using

```
var stringwithoutspecialCharacter = "testwordwithpunctiuation.".replace(/[^\w\s!?]/g, '');
```

The problem is that I do not know which special character will appear (that needs removing). However I do need to be able to access the removed special character after I've run some code with the word without the special character.

Example inputs:

```
"test".
(temporary)
foo,
```

Desired output:

```
['"','test','"',"."]
['(','temporary',')']
['foo',',']
```

How could this be achieved in javascript?

Comment: Can you add some example inputs, and corresponding outputs you need to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: To get both valid and invalid characters, change the regular expression**
Quick solution is to define an array to collect the matches.
Then pass in a function into your `replace()` call

```
var matches = [];
var matcher = function(match, offset, string) {
    matches.push(match);
    return '';
}
var stringwithoutspecialCharacter = "testwordwithpunctiuation.".replace(/[^\w\s!?]|[\w\s!?]+/g, matcher);
console.log("Matches: " + matches);
```

Comment: You answered my question very good considering I failed to explain exactly what I need. This works for the scenario I typed. If you would please look at my newly attached inputs/outputs, would you by any chance know how to achieve that as well?

Comment: @telv I've updated the answer. To solve your new question, I updated the regex to also catch one or more valid characters as a separate group