# Find the replaced part in a string using Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function str_replace(str , part_to_replace , replace_with) { 
var res = str.replace(part_to_replace , replace_with);
return res;
}
console.log(str_replace("amir" , "ir" , "er")) //returns "amer"
```

I want the function to return "e" which is the only part that changed aka replaced part so how i am supposed to do that ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Comment: why do you want `'e'`, and how does it come?

Comment: it's not something that bothers me alot but i want to do it for learning puroposes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46653425/get-replaced-characters-with-javascript-regex-replace

Comment: i am still learning u know?

Comment: A simple way would be to save the old string and compare it to the new one using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024102/javascript-compare-strings-and-get-end-difference)

Comment: @Nina e is just an example so u can get my point

Comment: compare `part_to_replace` with `replace_with` and keep only letters and indexes that do not match. In your example it is letter `e` index `0`. Another example though could contain letters in non consecutive positions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate all characters and take only the changed ones.

```js
function check(a, b) {
    if (a.length !== b.length) { return; }
    
    return b
        .split('')                // take an array
        .filter(function (c, i) { // filter
            return a[i] !== c;    // check characters
        })
        .join('');                // return string
}

function str_replace(str, part_to_replace, replace_with) {
    return str.replace(part_to_replace, replace_with);
}

console.log(str_replace("amir", "ir", "er"));
console.log(check("amir", str_replace("amir", "ir", "er")));
```

Comment: This is a good answer, very clean. One issue may be that it simply returns if the two strings are not the same length. I think it is fair to assume that the replaced part may be longer than the part replaced.

Comment: @vincecampanale, it could be shorter as well. what would you like to return in case of unequal length?

Comment: Yep could be shorter too :) -- not sure what the OP wants in this case. I was thinking it would be a simple difference between the two strings, regardless of length. Comparing each index, if the character isn't the same, the character at that index (in the new string) gets returned.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want an array of characters in the new string that were not present in the old one. This will do the trick:

```
function getDifference(oldStr, newStr) {
  // .split('') turns your string into an array of characters
  var oldSplit = oldStr.split(''); 
  var newSplit = newStr.split('');

  // then compare the arrays and get the difference
  var diff = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < newSplit.length; i++) {
    if (newSplit[i] !== oldSplit[i]) {
      diff.push(newSplit[i]);
    }
  }
  return diff;
}

var diff = getDifference('amir', str_replace('amir', 'ir', 'er'));
console.log(diff); // e
```